# Custom Windows context menu shell command targetting documents: *.docx and *.pdf

Tags: windows-10, shell, pdf, context-menu, regedit

Currently I have a custom command for moving a selected file(s) to the correct cloud storage folder. I do this using the following (executed as a `.reg` file):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\document\shell\Cloud]
@="Move to Cloud Folder"
"Icon"="%SystemRoot%//system32//shell32.dll,-16752"
"MultiSelectModel"="Player"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\document\shell\Cloud\command]
@="\"C:\\Move to Cloud Folder.exe\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\Cloud]
@="Move to Cloud Folder"
"Icon"="%SystemRoot%//system32//shell32.dll,-16752"
"MultiSelectModel"="Player"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\Cloud\command]
@="\"C:\\Move to Cloud Folder.exe\" \"%1\""
```

This works fine for image types: e.g. `pic.bmp`. However, for `*.docx` or `*.pdf`, the command is not listed when right-clicking on either file type. I have checked and both file types have their perceived type set as `document` as they should.

I do not want to use `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*]`. How do I target these file types (`*.docx` and `*.pdf`)? Any ideas why the method I use for `images` does not work for `documents`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an older application called [ContextEdit](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/ContextEdit.shtml) I was able to target the required file types and produce the following reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; PDF files (*.pdf) viewed using Chrome browser

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\Cloud]
@="Move to Cloud Folder"
"Icon"="%SystemRoot%//system32//shell32.dll,-16752"
"MultiSelectModel"="Player"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\Cloud\command]
@="\"C:\\Move to Cloud Folder.exe\" \"%1\""

; Word files (*.docx)

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Cloud]
@="Move to Cloud Folder"
"Icon"="%SystemRoot%//system32//shell32.dll,-16752"
"MultiSelectModel"="Player"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Cloud\command]
@="\"C:\\Move to Cloud Folder.exe\" \"%1\""
```

---

> Any ideas why the method I use for `images` does not work for `documents`?

Still do not have an answer for this